# C# Stream.CanSeek property, This Stream Doesn't Support Seeking

Tags: c#, http, httprequest

Me and my friend are trying to send http request that we received from the client

```cs
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:3294/discord/");
            listener.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();

            Stream body = context.Request.InputStream;
            Encoding encoding = context.Request.ContentEncoding;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(body, encoding);
            
            if (body != null)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[body.Length];
                body.Read(buffer, 0, (int)body.Length);

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/818198824439004692/jfe2zN93Ca0VOVry0uIBe6xvmx74tYP9QdaEFH--sDMSscKXcgxAYvlu3RSYwb32oZra");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = context.Response.ContentType;

                request.ContentLength = body.Length;
                Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                newStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
```

but I am getting an error `System.NotSupportedException: 'This stream does not support seek operations.'` when I try accessing `body.Length`
and I noticed there is `CanSeek` property in `Stream` class but it is has only `get`.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If you can't Seek a stream, you can't typically know its [`Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.length?view=net-5.0) either. Why not pass on the source request's declared Content Length?

Comment: "I noticed there is CanSeek property in Stream class but it is has only get" - yes, that's because it's meant to tell you whether or not the stream implementation *does* support seeking. It's not meant to allow you to *force* it to allow seeking.

Comment: @Llama "Why not pass on the source request's declared Content Length?" wdym?

Comment: As far as I understand it, you're trying to stream a request from ASP.NET to another service using `HttpWebRequest`. The request to your API will typically have a Content-Length declared.

Comment: Oh, I see you're using `HttpListener`. This will also provide you with the client headers, I should think.

Comment: I never used asp.net ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

You can't change a non-seekable stream to magically become seekable - in this case, the stream is the set of bytes arriving over the network (perhaps after some TLS/etc work). If you need the data to be seekable, you'll need to buffer (copy) it somewhere else (often a `MemoryStream`), and seek on *that*. The preferred option, however, is usually to remove the need to seek the data in the first place.

Comment: now it is giving me bad request error :( https://pastebin.com/Mu6c2f1t