'((System.Net.Http.HttpBaseStream)stream).Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
I'm getting this error from a behavior I don't understand:
Exception screenshot
I've looked online to try to find a solution but nothing worked or applied to my case.
It says that Stream.Length threw an exception but as I found online, people said to check the .CanSeek method and for each stream open I checked and they all returned true.
Here's the proof that it reads the length of the stream:
Debug output ( Sorry for the quality, screenshots were removing the debug output window ).
And this is right before returning the item, in this case a user, and everything works before it.
Here's my code for this method:
public async Task<RegistrationResponse> RegisterAsync(RegistrationRequest body)
{
    // Create a new instance of the IHttpClientFactory
    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("default");

    // Create a MemoryStream to be able to use compression
    using (var memoryContentStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(memoryContentStream, body);

        // CAN SEEK returns true
        var canSeek = memoryContentStream.CanSeek;

        memoryContentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Use HttpRequestMessage instead of the .PostAsync shortcut but either could be used
        using (var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(
                   HttpMethod.Post,
                   "/api/Accounts/register"))
        {
            // Add headers to the call
            httpRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            httpRequest.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));

            using (var compressedMemoryContentStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Compress the content
                using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(
                           compressedMemoryContentStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    memoryContentStream.CopyTo(gzipStream);
                    gzipStream.Flush();
                    compressedMemoryContentStream.Position = 0;

                    // CAN SEEK returns true
                    var canSeek2 = compressedMemoryContentStream.CanSeek;

                    // Create a stream
                    using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(compressedMemoryContentStream))
                    {
                        // Add headers to the call
                        streamContent.Headers.ContentType =
                            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                        streamContent.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip");


                        httpRequest.Content = streamContent;

                        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(
                            httpRequest,
                            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                        // THIS IS WHERE IT DOESN'T WORK ANYMORE, even thought .Content shows the length of the stream
                        var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                        var user = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<RegistrationResponse>(stream);

                        return user;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Here's another picture for the stack errors:
Stacks Locals
UPDATE
Here's the code that calls the stream method:
async Task ValidSubmit()
{
    try
    {
        var catId = _configuration["OtherCategory"];
        _processing = true;
        var newRequest = new RegistrationRequest()
                {
                    FirstName = RegistrationRequest.FirstName,
                    LastName = RegistrationRequest.LastName,
                    CategoryId = Guid.Parse(catId),
                    PhoneNumber = RegistrationRequest.PhoneNumber,
                    Password = RegistrationRequest.Password
                };

        // RegistrationRequest.CategoryId = Guid.Parse(this.CategoryId);
        IsSuccess = true;
        await AuthenticationService.RegisterAsync(newRequest);
        // SuccessNotification();
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("code-verification");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        throw;
    }
}

And what Exception e throws here is:

"Cannot access a closed stream"
at >System.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException_StreamClosed(String
objectName)
at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.PurgeBuffers(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.Stream.Close()
at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.Stream.Close()
at Website.UI.Services.AuthenticationService.d__2.MoveNext()
in
C:\Users\something\source\repos\Website.Website\Website.UI\Services\AuthenticationService.cs:line
75
at Website.UI.Components.Pages.PageComponents.SignUpComponent.d__8.MoveNext()
in
C:\Users\something\source\repos\Website.Website\Website.UI\Components\Pages\PageComponents\SignUpComponent.razor:line
114


Please show the full stack trace, as text not images. Also are you only getting the exception when using the debugger viewer? Because I wouldn't expect that stream to work after desrializing (and auto-closing).

Your "proof" screenshot says that the headers of the response contains values. It does not say anything about the stream instance

So I don't know how to get the full stack trace but here's what I'm getting from the Locals list

Posted a pic btw

BTW in your exception screenshot the value of the property CanSeek is false so that exception is not surprising at all - and that response stream is not depending on any other stream of your code so it does not matter in what state they are

You can try to use var user = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<RegistrationResponse>(); - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpcontentjsonextensions.readfromjsonasync?view=net-8.0#system-net-http-json-httpcontentjsonextensions-readfromjsonasync-1(system-net-http-httpcontent-system-threading-cancellationtoken)

@SirRufo first off thank you for your help. If it doesn't use the stream it might work but I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work and how can I solve this ? Because in the case of registration I don't need to return values but for my other methods it's necessary. Do you know what I should do to make it work ?

This can help u to understand better why u need CanSeek: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66965985/c-sharp-stream-canseek-property-this-stream-doesnt-support-seeking

@DA ok but is that what the problem is ? Is my issue related to ,CanSeek ? And if so, could you tell me how ? Thank you.

I'm confused about why you care whether the stream is seekable or can return a length. None of your code depends on that. You say // THIS IS WHERE IT DOESN'T WORK ANYMORE but haven't shown what actually isn't working.

What I mean is that up to this line everything returns a value, is seekable etc. I don't really care that it is seekable I just want to be able to return the value but because of the exception returned I can't deserialize the json and that's a problem. Also I'd like to know if it is because of my code or something that I can't deserialize it literally at the end. @Charlieface the pictures I've posted are the ones explaining what isn't working, hopefully it's enough, I don't really know what information I can get about the issue other than what I posted I'm sorry.

The seekability was only important because people online were saying it is in order for this to work so I've put it here for people to see it is seekable.

You keep showing the debugger view, and while I can see that certain properties throw errors, I'm not seeing an actual exception in the code. It's not necessary for every property to return correctly, it's quite normal for a stream not to be seekable. Please show which line is causing an exception, with the full exception message and stack trace. And please paste as text, not images, like we're telling you.

@Charlieface I think I got the right stack trace this time, updated the post

It seems that at some point the compressedMemoryContent is being closed too early. Exactly why that is the case is not clear, but it's entirely unrelated to your debugger screenshots of .Length and CanSeek failing, which is quite normal for many types of streams. Do not attempt to use the debugger view on a Stream, it quite often messes up the stream and you need to restart. If you need to debug then use local variables or WriteLine.
You can simplify the code significantly, as well as add in missing usings, and hopefully that will resolve your issue.
public async Task<RegistrationResponse> RegisterAsync(RegistrationRequest body)
{
    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("default");

    using var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(
                   HttpMethod.Post,
                   "/api/Accounts/register"));
    httpRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    httpRequest.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));

    using var compressedMemoryContentStream = new MemoryStream();
    // NOTE the use of leaveOpen, so we don't need to flush it
    using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(
               compressedMemoryContentStream, CompressionMode.Compress, leaveOpen: true))
    {
         // NOTE serialize directly to gzip, no need for second memstream
         await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(gzipStream, body);
    }

    compressedMemoryContentStream.Position = 0;  // rewind

    using var streamContent = new StreamContent(compressedMemoryContentStream);
    streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    streamContent.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip");
    httpRequest.Content = streamContent;

    using var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(
                            httpRequest,
                            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var user = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<RegistrationResponse>(stream);
    return user;
}

Even after making these changes you are reporting that you get all nulls. This seems to be because you have a case mismatch between the property names and your JSON, for example name and Name.
To fix this, you can either set the deserializer to case-insensitive:
static JsonSerializerOptions _options = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerOptions.Default)
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
};

var user = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<RegistrationResponse>(stream, _options);

Or set each property with a name explicitly
public class MyData
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


The httpRequest is in a using statement already. It's not in a using {} block if that's what you're asking, but the effect is basically the same and it's easier to read this newer syntax. I don't know why it's happening again, the only other thing I can suggest is maybe it's the server. I suggest you use a transparent proxy like Fiddler to compare a working and non-working request, maybe you're missing a header or something?

That's weird because the server is localhost, so I'd imagine it shouldn't have any problem with loss of data, it's confusing lol

I’m just realizing it, but could it be because my API doesn’t support streaming yet ?

Sorry Charlie, I was kind of confused, but after testing a lot of stuff, I think I figured it out. So I think the problem is System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer, because when I tried the defaultway to use the HttpClient, with .ReadAsStringAsync() it still didn't work but when I used Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert with the default way it worked ! So now I want to use that but there are a couple details I don't know how to modify: how to change JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(gzipStream, body); to adapt to JsonConvert ? Also can I make it use  Streams with .DeserializeObject() ? Thank you

I didn't get any error but it just wouldn't deserialize the data into the object in this line var user = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<AuthenticationResponse>(string);, all the properties would be null, as opposed to the other one which would fill the data in.

Sounds like you have fields instead of properties, or private instead of public, or uppercase/lowercase mismatch.

Could it be a camel case option issue ( like I saw in the course from which I got this code ) ? But in this case, why would it work with JsonConvert If one of these issues is present?

Because Newtonsoft is case-insensitive by default, and JsonSerializer is case-sensitive. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/character-casing

The case insensitivity was the solution brother ! Thank you so much, can you add it to the DeserializeAsync(stream, new JsonSerializerOptions…); line and mention that this is the solution so that I can mark it as the answer ? Thank you for your help Charlie.

OK have edited it.
